# How do I install dependencies when cross compiling haskell code?

Tags: haskell, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, ghc, cabal-install

I've successfully created a ghc cross compiler, that allows me to compile haskell code for armv6h (raspberry pi in my case) from my x64 linux machine. 
I've successfully run a hello world program on the raspberry.

No I want to build my real app, which has a lot of dependencies on other haskell modules.
When I compile for x64 I simply do

```
cabal install dependenciy1 depenency2 ...
```

I know I could make my own programm a cabal-project an automate this step. But that's not the point here.

When I try to use the cross-compiler

```
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ghc --make myapp.hs
```

It tells me about modules it could not find. Of course, they are not installed!

I read https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/CrossCompiling
and according to that I tried

```
cabal --with-ghc=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ghc --with-ghc-pkg=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ghc-pkg --with-ld=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ld install random
```

random is the depenency I'm trying to install here. I get the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring random-1.0.1.3...
Failed to install random-1.0.1.3
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /home/daniel/.cabal/logs/random-1.0.1.3.log ):
/home/daniel/.cabal/setup-exe-cache/setup-Cabal-1.18.1.3-arm-linux-ghc-7.8.3.20140804: /home/daniel/.cabal/setup-exe-cache/setup-Cabal-1.18.1.3-arm-linux-ghc-7.8.3.20140804:      cannot execute binary file
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
random-1.0.1.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 126
```

When I do

```
file /home/daniel/.cabal/setup-exe-cache/setup-Cabal-1.18.1.3-arm-linux-ghc-7.8.3.20140804
```

I get

```
/home/daniel/.cabal/setup-exe-cache/setup-Cabal-1.18.1.3-arm-linux-ghc-7.8.3.20140804: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.10.2, not stripped
```

No wonder it can't execute it. It's compiled for arm.

Am I missing something here? 
My goal is to pull in all dependencies, then create a statically linked app that I can deploy on my raspberry.

Comment: can you try `cabal get random`, then cd to the `random-???` directory, and then `runhaskell ./Setup.hs install --with-ghc=... ...` ?

Comment: When I do that I get `unrecognized 'install' option \`--with-ghc=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ghc'

unrecognized 'install' option \`--with-ghc-pkg=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ghc-pkg'

unrecognized 'install' option \`--with-ld=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ld'`

Comment: Oh, seems you need to do `runhaskell ./Setup.hs configure --with...`, then `runhaskell ./Setup.hs build` and finally `runhaskell ./Setup.hs install`.

Comment: okay, that seems to work. But now when I try to link my app against it, the linker says: `/home/daniel/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/daniel/.cabal/lib/arm-linux-ghc-7.8.3.20140804/random-1.0.1.3/libHSrandom-1.0.1.3.a when searching for -lHSrandom-1.0.1.3`

Comment: @DanielSchmitz Try to disabling stripping when configuring, `--disable-library-stripping` and `--disable-executable-stripping`

Comment: @bennofs you probably should make a real answer to let us upvote it

Comment: Also, if the package uses `hsc2hs`, make sure it gets `-x` flag, otherwise it will produce `Storable` instances for host architecture instead of target. IIRC I needed it for `network`, otherwise it crashed at runtime.

Comment: @Yuras: disabling stripping did it. I can now compile and link a static binary and execute it on the pi :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To understand this error, you need to know how `cabal install` works internally. In essence, it will perform the following steps:

1. Download and unpack the source code
2. Compile `Setup.hs` (this file is used for customization of the build system, for example, you can implement some hooks to run additional haskell code in the `configure` phase).
3. Run `setup configure <configure flags> && setup build && setup install`

The problem is now that `cabal install` uses the GHC given by `--with-ghc` also for step 2, but the executable produced by that step must run on the host system!

A workaround is to do the steps manually, which means you have full control. First, get the source:

```
$ cabal get random
Downloading random-1.0.1.3...
Unpacking to random-1.0.1.3/
$ cd random-1.0.1.3
```

Then, compile `Setup.hs`, using the *host* ghc:

```
$ ghc ./Setup.hs -o setup
```

And finally, configure, build and install. As suggested by @Yuras in a comment, we also add the `-x` option for running `hsc2hs`:

```
$ ./setup configure ----with-ghc=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ghc --with-ghc-pkg=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ghc-pkg --with-ld=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ld --hsc2hs-options=-x
$ ./setup build && ./setup install
```

There is already a cabal issue about this: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2085

Comment: Should `ghc ./Setup.hs -osetup` be `ghc ./Setup.hs -o setup` with a space between `-o` and `setup`? I received `unrecognised flags: -osetup` without the space.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Oh, that's surprising, you indeed need a space. I wonder why `-packagelens` works without a space then though ...

Comment: Is there actually a way to simulate what cabal is doing in a script? It would be helpful to be able to specify `builddir` option and have support for sandboxes...