# cabal cross-compile for ARM issue with hsc2hs

Tags: linux, haskell, arm, cross-compiling, hsc2hs

I am trying to cross-compile `cabal-install` for ARM. It has come down to installing the prerequisite packages one-by-one. I was able to configure, build and install some of the packages by following this page:

[How do I install dependencies when cross compiling haskell code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765893/how-do-i-install-dependencies-when-cross-compiling-haskell-code)

Until I got to the `network` package where I got this error after `./Setup build`:

```
Setup: The program hsc2hs is required but it could not be found
```

After this I added the

```
--with-hsc2hs=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-hsc2hs
```

switch to my configure, but this time I ran into

```
/opt/ghc-cross-7.8.3/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-hsc2hs: line 29: /opt/ghc-cross-7.8.3/lib/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-ghc-7.8.3/bin/hsc2hs: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Apparently my `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-hsc2hs` tool is not running on my host. Why is this happening? And why, for instance, `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-ghc` is working but not `hsc2hs`? And lastly, is there workaround for installing my original `network` package?

Comment: These are good questions. But, in order to *use* your cross-compiled cabal-install, you need a GHC that runs on ARM, right? If you have that, might it not be easier to do the bootstrap entirely on ARM using that compiler, rather than your cross-compiler? I can't imagine it would take too long.

Comment: I tried that but my ARM system actually hangs during 'make' which is another strange observation. I guess that is because my RAM is small < 1GB?

Comment: If you're trying to use GHC 7.10 on ARM, you probably want the current `master` branch. A show-stopper GHCi bug was fixed after 7.10.2 and 7.10.3 isn't out yet. I don't know anything else about it though.

Comment: Actaully I only want 7.8.3 because the software I eventually want to build for ARM is only supported and tested with this version.